# YouTube iframe API play-state for unavailable in region videos

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I am using the YouTube iFrame to load and play an array of videos by their YT ID,

On occasion, the video is blocked in the visitors region, and in which case it should skip to the next one.

The API doesn't seem to give events on this occasion, or have a play-state related to un-playable videos (https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_status)

At the moment I'm trying to get round this by setting a timeout and skipping if the video is loaded and then doesn't play after 3333ms, but that also skips if the video takes a while to load because of slow connections.

Does anyone know of a good technique to detect if a video is blocked?

Comment: How do you determine which video IDs to add to the array? Maybe you could check if the video is blocked and if so, exclude it from the array.

Comment: It's a JSON array of ID's, but different videos are blocked in different countries.

Comment: Do you catch the `onError` event and do you get anything when trying to play a restricted video?

Comment: Yes, I skip when onError, but it looks like restricted videos don't trigger an onError

Comment: OK - that's weird. I get a 150 error when I try and play a restricted video. I think 150 means 'The owner of the requested video does not allow it to be played in embedded players'. The video I am testing on is 'MSD-bfNkbPM' - don't ask - it was the first one I could find that is not accessible in the UK!

Comment: Ah thanks, I'll see if I can test using that. Apparently my technique is working okay (my friends tested it in Germany, and pretty much everything is blocked there!)